# Why cant i apply padding to the website in the div tag where i defined class as "container-fluid" and wrote the css code for the same

Tags: html, css

Here in section tag(id="title") I used  the tag div in which I define the class="container-fluid" for this website and since I want padding of 3% from top and bottom and 15% from left and right I applied CSS with .container-fluid in which I wrote padding 3% 15%; and save the changes but the left and right padding(15%) is not reflecting in the website preview

```css
#title{
  background-color: #ff4c68;
}
h1{
  font-family: Montserrat-Black 900;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.container-fluid {
  padding: 3% 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid">


      <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Tindog</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>



      <!-- Title -->
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
          <button type="button">Download</button>
          <button type="button">Download</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- Features -->

  <section id="features">

    <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
    <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>

    <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
    <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>

    <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
    <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>

  </section>


  <!-- Testimonials -->

  <section id="testimonials">

    <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
    <img src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
    <em>Pebbles, New York</em>

    <!-- <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
    <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
    <em>Beverly, Illinois</em> -->

  </section>


  <!-- Press -->

  <section id="press">
    <img src="images/techcrunch.png" alt="tc-logo">
    <img src="images/tnw.png" alt="tnw-logo">
    <img src="images/bizinsider.png" alt="biz-insider-logo">
    <img src="images/mashable.png" alt="mashable-logo">

  </section>


  <!-- Pricing -->

  <section id="pricing">

    <h2>A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
    <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>


    <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
    <h2>Free</h2>
    <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
    <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>


    <h3>Labrador</h3>
    <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
    <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
    <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>


    <h3>Mastiff</h3>
    <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
    <p>Pirority Listing</p>
    <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
    <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>

  </section>


  <!-- Call to Action -->

  <section id="cta">

    <h3>Find the True Love of Your Dog's Life Today.</h3>
    <button type="button">Download</button>
    <button type="button">Download</button>

  </section>


  <!-- Footer -->

  <footer id="footer">

    <p>© Copyright 2018 TinDog</p>

  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone's doing Angela's bootcamp here ... ;)

As Imran told you, you should always put the link of the stylesheet you use on the last position, below all the other stylesheets, like bootstrap or a reset, for example. Remember that css is cascading stylesheet, which means that the last information will override those which are given above, so your own style gives you the control of the appearance of your app.

Js scripts links are different, though it looks like being a better practice to put them just before your body close tag.

You can do like this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="someStyle.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="anotherStyle.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="anotherAnotherStyle.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="thenYourStyle.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex rerum, 
              modi delectus aliquid consequuntur perspiciatis veniam officiis voluptate 
              vel ducimus error, 
              blanditiis corporis expedita sint aspernatur commodi facilis. Magni, culpa.</p>
      </div>
      <script src="someScript.js"></script>
      <script src="anotherScript.js"></script>
      <script src="thenYourScript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

Place this after using bootstrap links just before closing `</head>`. Your CSS is over-written by bootstrap CSS.

What I mean is you need to do this:

```
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>TinDog</title>

     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
     <link
       href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?     family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
```

Comment: but then why red color is applied which i wrote in css in the id="title"?

Comment: Good Question: The reason is  id had more specificity than class.

Comment: So what should be the sequence for linking bootstrap,css, javascript in html to work it fine?

Comment: Dear @Mustafa : If you visit : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template , you will see a starter template. Whenever you need to use Bootstrap use this template. But Just after <title></title> add you custom CSS link. <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"> Rest everything is shown.

Comment: Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks you helped me a lot.